# Fixing leak in tub overflow with old style drain closer

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub, old-house, overflow

I couldn't find any examples of my tub drain lever online, so I can't figure out how to remove it. The overflow is leaking, so I'd like to open it up and see what the gasket is like to replace it. On the back of the tub, it looks like there's some corrosion at that point, so that's probably the culprit.

I got the handle loose, but the overflow cap is blocking my access to screws. I can't get the handle out of the assembly, it's connected somehow to the tub drain.

Pix:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I was able to loosen the lever and cap by first removing a center screw and then unscrewing a center hex nut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! Figured I'd answer my own question in case someone else has a similar lever. The lever handle was stuck onto the shaft. I just needed to force it off.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not unusual just old , make sure to accept your answer so people can see there is a solution.